# Why doesn't fusing two loops together produce the same result as a nested loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, merge, nested-loops

(Using python 2)

I was suggested to fuse my two of my loops together to speed up my code that was taking way too long.

So instead of this:

```
for timestep in range(0,100): 
     for xn in xrange(0,npoints):
          for step in xrange(0,npoints):


               fx=somefunction[xn]+somefunction[step]

               print fx
```

I used this:

```
for timestep in xrange(0,100):
     for step, xn in itertools.product([0,npoints-1],[0,npoints-1]):


          fx=somefunction[xn]+somefunction[step]

          print fx
```

but I got two very different results when I printed out my function, fx.

For the nested loop (the first block of code), I got a list of 999 numbers (which was the correct length).

However, when I tried to merge the two loops together (second block of code), I only got four out of the 999 numbers I was supposed to get in my list.

Am I merging my for-loop wrong? Is there another way to merge a nested for loop together that will still help speed up my code?

Comment: You did merge your loops wrong, but you *also* changed the `fx` computation. It might have been easier for you to spot that if you didn't write 3-page-wide lines.

Comment: Actually, that was just a typo in my post. Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Comment: `[0, npoints-1]` is not a list of number between 0 and `npoints - 1`; it's a list with exactly 2 elements. Why did you stop using `xrange`?

Comment: Can you post your corrected answer as the answer?

Comment: @chepner That's what I was kind of thinking at first too, but I tried it with round brackets too and got the same thing. Are you just not able to use a list of numbers between two points with the itertools function?

Comment: You still need to use `xrange()` objects, `[0,npoints-1]` is a list with two integer values, something completely different.

Comment: `(0, n_points-1)` is a tuple. Why do you think you need to stop using `xrange` to generate your sequence of numbers just because you are using `product`? `product(xrange(0, n_points), xrange(0, n_points))` (or better yet, `product(xrange(0, n_points), repeat=2)`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Pieters I tried this too, but it came back telling me TypeError: an integer is required.. So I thought it wasn't the correct format for itertools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting different results because you aren't working with the same sequences. You still need `xrange`, as `product` takes *iterables*, not pairs of end points, as its arguments.

```
for step, xn in itertools.product(xrange(0, npoints), repeat=2):
```

With `product([0,n_points-1], [0,n_points-1])`, you are only iterating over tuples: `(0,0)`, `(0,n_points-1)`, `(n_points-1,0)`, and `(n_points-1,n_points-1)`, rather than the O(`n_points**2`) different tuples you want.`